# Can I attack a PRNG using a differential or linear cryptanalysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis

I modified the generation key function of XTEA using a PRNG with 128 bits. I have to attack it using both differential and linear cryptanalysis but I don't see how, it's possible to attack a PRNG?

Comment: **What research have you done?** I'm asking because sharing research efforts helps everyone! Tell us what research you did, what you found, and why it didn’t meet your needs. That shows users you took time trying to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and (most important) it helps you to get more relevant on-point answers. In case of doubt, you can start by searching this site for related Q&As that might shed light on your question. At worst it will help you frame [*“a better question”*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); at best it might even answer it.

Comment: Both of these attacks require (at least) known plaintext-ciphertext pairs to work, do you have this with a PRNG?